# iOS 16 - remove Home from Control Centre

Tags: ios, homekit, control-center

Ever since updating to iOS 16, I now have this Home section added to my Control Centre.
I neither need nor want this. Home is not enabled as one of my Control Centre items, yet this sits here prompting me to set up some 'accessories and scenes' for equipment I don't own… [I've tried clicking the helpful 'Open Home' in the hope it would be satisfied, but I can't do anything with it, as I have nothing to configure.]

This, combined with the fact the entire screen now sits much lower than it used to, wasting an entire row at the top, pushes all the icons I **do** want off the bottom of the screen.

Is there any way to get rid of it?

[image]

Inside the Home app I found prefs to switch off 'suggestions' and also removed the default 'home' it had decided I needed to get started. No joy.

*Late edit*
Mentioned in comments & in an answer is to switch off 'Show Home Controls', just below 'Access within apps'. I do not have this option…

[image]

Comment: There are two "Home" options in Control Centre, one for home controls (above the list of items) and one as a control item. Assume you toggled both.

Comment: I just have one called 'Home' currently [& always has been] disabled. Maybe to get 'home controls' you first need to have set up some actual controls/devices?

Comment: hnh… and it's now disappeared. Whatever I did in removing the default 'scene' with a 10 minute delayed reaction has actually removed the section I wanted rid of. Not really sure how that worked.

Comment: LOL. Let's hope it stays that way.

Comment: Hope so. I guess this Q can go bye-bye now, as I don't really know what I did to fix it.

Comment: Delete, or wait a few days to see whether somebody knows a reproducible way.

Comment: I can hang on, no worries ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Settings** → **Control Centre** → **Show Home Controls**.

[image]

I tried this on a device without a Home, which still showed the section in Control Center as you have in your screenshot, and with a Home where that section had controls. Turning off this option in Settings removed the section in both cases.

This is different to the Home option in the list of Control Center items in Settings. That controls a separate button for showing the Home app or holding for controls.

Comment: nohillside mentioned that earlier. I just don't have that switch at all. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaGus.jpg I do have the regular 'Home' switch down the disabled end of the list.